# Angular troubles

Tags: angularjs

Let's take [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) simple example. When I build it on a page not in Sharepoint context it works. Within Sharepoint context it doesn't work correctly. If I bind two fields to the same object they get updated when i change one, so the binding works as supposed. But when I call a function using a button with ng-click, all the objects result to be undefined.

My snippets:

HTML

```
   <div class="mainTable" ng-app="app" ng-controller="partnerProvisionEmailCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="year" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="year" />
        <input type="button" value="Send Email" ng-click="sendEmail()"/>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT (App.js)

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['appControllers']);
```

SCRIPT (Controller.js)

```
"use strict";

var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

appControllers.controller('partnerProvisionEmailCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.sendEmail = function(){
        // $scope.year is undefined!!!!
    }
}]);
```

My guess is that there is something in Sharepoint javascript part that creates conflict...Outside Sharepoint i get the right value.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
I repeat, as standalone my code works! In Sharepoint it doesn't!

Comment: is this complete snippet of your code? with no controller and module defined? you can't make angularJS work like that

Comment: Come on guys...how could i say that the `$scope.year` is undefined? Furthermore, i wrote `...two fields to the same object they get updated when i change one...`. Do you really want the complete code?

Comment: So...for your interest i added the part to "complete" it.

Comment: Shouldn't the ng-app attribute be `ng-app="appControllers"`? Also, note that`$scope.year` should initially be `undefined`

Comment: Did you read ALL my description? i wrote that outside sharepoint context the same code WORKS!

Comment: I read all your code, and the code is wrong

Comment: Really? Then tell my why outside Sharepoint it works.

Comment: Here is a [plnkr with your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/sOh24jHb4egzTuWBIrUZ?p=preview) (doesn't work) , and here is [a plnkr with my suggestion](http://plnkr.co/edit/enae5jmc2odCwonpPl2R?p=preview). I understand you probably have something like the last one working for you, I just made a comment about your code, which is all I can see. I can't see your wiring, your setup, your angular version, your SharePoint version. I can however tell you I have several Angular-based solutions working in several SP environments

Comment: I'm not saying that it doesn't work at all. I'm saying that all the values defined in the $scope are undefined within my function, but only in SP Context. As your plunker, if i write it as a standalone page, it works.

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me without any error in sharepoint (tried it in wiki as well as html page) please check for error in browser console, make sure you have `angular.min.js.map` in same folder where `angular.js` is stored on local pc as  in it will refer to previous one internally

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app"  ng-controller="partnerProvisionEmailCtrl">
 Enter Year:
    <input type="text" ng-model="year"/>
     <input type="text" ng-model="year"/>
    <button ng-click='sendEmail()'>greet</button>
  <hr/>
  {{year}}
</div>
```

App.js

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['appControllers']);
```

Controller.js

```
  "use strict";
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);
appControllers.controller('partnerProvisionEmailCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sendEmail = function(){
        // $scope.year is undefined!!!!
        alert($scope.year)
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I don't know what to say. In my case it doesn't work...

Comment: open your SharePoint site in Chrome press F12 hit the URL and check if you have error in browser console

Comment: I already checked it. No errors.